# Mongoose/Typegoose Error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I have this model:

```
import { prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

export class ChildDAO {
    @prop({ index: true, required: true })
    childId!: number;
    @prop({ index: true })
    name?: string;
    @prop({ index: true })
    surname?: string;
}

export class ParentDAO {
    @prop({ index: true, default: () => new Date() })
    createdAt?: Date;

    @prop({ ref: ChildDAO })
    child?: Ref<ChildDAO>;
    
    // other attributes are regular strings or numbers, some indexed, some required, nothing special
}
```

Why am I getting

`ValidationError: ParentDAO validation failed: child: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ name: 'Max', surname: 'Mustermann', ... }`

when trying to save an object?

EDIT My setup code:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    mongoClient = await require('mongoose').connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        dbName
    });
    ParentModel = getModelForClass(ParentDAO, {schemaOptions: {collection: 'parents'}});
    ChildModel = getModelForClass(ChildDAO, {schemaOptions: {collection: 'children'}});
});
```

And the saving method which get's called in a test:

```
export class StorageService {
    static async saveParent(parent: Parent): Promise<ParentDAO> {
        const ParentModel = getModelForClass(ParentDAO);
        return ParentModel.create({
            ...parent
        } as ParentDAO);
    }
}
```

I should not without the Ref (with a single, nested collection) this all works fine.

So how do I set up nested collections correctly?

Comment: could you also provide the code surrounding the save?

Comment: `ObjectId` is the type of `_id` of the document. and you are trying to save `"{ name: 'Max', surname: 'Mustermann', ... }` as value of `_id` . so It says It cannot be added as `ObjectId` since it is not of type `ObjectId`

Comment: @hasezoey Thank you for replying :) I updated the code.

Comment: @RadicalEdward so what is the best practice here? I just want to have 1 Child to M Parents relationship, how do I generate references in the correct way?

Comment: @Phil make sure you are not setting value of `_id` explicitly if you have defined its type as `ObjectId` . and while finding document with `_id` always pass value thats valid as `ObjectId` type

Comment: @RadicalEdward I am not doing any of that. I am just saving the Parent object. Perhaps I need to save the Child manually first? The above code is all there is except some boring fields on the models.

Comment: @hasezoey I am still struggling with this issue. The docs for typegoose show exactly the same structure: `@prop({ ref: Car })
  public car?: Ref<Car>;` where `class Car { @prop() public model?: string; }`, my DAOs are not special in any way. So is the setup wrong here or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guessing form the provided code, you are trying to save an reference and think that if it doesn't exists, it gets created, which is **not** what is happening, for an reference you need to either provide an ObjectId (or the reference's _id type) or an instance of an Document (to automatically get the `_id`)

---

(comment of @Phil)

> I am not doing any of that. I am just saving the Parent object. Perhaps I need to save the Child manually first? The above code is all there is except some boring fields on the models.

exactly, you need to save the child manually and provide the id then to the parent